# How can I get a results page using bind params to return query from drop down

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working through an online tutorial to rewrite my results page using bind params. I thought I understood it fairly well but I can't get it to work so obviously, I don't. I've tried everything I thought logical plus some things that were not but still all I get is a blank page.
This is the drop down.

```
 <form action="search3.php" method="post" >

<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost,user,password,database);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM engravers ORDER BY Country";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

?>
<select name="dropdown">
<?php

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$row['Country']}\">";
    echo $row['Country'];
    echo "</option>";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
</select>

          <input type="submit"  />   
          </form>
```

And this is the results page.It is pretty much copied from the tutorial except in the tutorial $queryparam would have been equal to $_POST['Country']. As that didn't work I've changed it to $_POST['dropdown'] which is the name of the drop down.

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password,);
if(!$connection){
echo"Could not connect to server";
};
mysqli_select_db($connection,'engraved_stamps');
if(!mysqli_select_db($connection,'engraved_stamps')){
echo"could not connect to database";
};
if(isset($_POST['dropdown']){
}

$stmt=mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT Key, Country, Year, Description, Images FROM engravers   WHERE Country=?");
$queryParam=$_POST['dropdown'];
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$queryParam);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$Key,$Country,$Year,$Description,$Images);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);


$img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/"; 
print '<table border="1" >';
while($row ->mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt); 
{

print '<tr>';
print '<td>'.$row["Key"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Year"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>';

print  '<td>'.'<img src="'.$img_url.$row['Images'].'" />'.'</td>'; 
print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';


$results->free();

$mysqli->close();
```

I want to get this working but I also want to know why things work or don't.

Answer (score 0):

Since writing the above, I've found a much neater way to do this which is working so for any other newbies like me, this is the code. The first lines to connect to the database are the same. then...

```
if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])){

}else{
 echo "No input";
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID,Country,Year,Description,Images FROM engravers WHERE Country = ? ORDER BY ID");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['dropdown']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ID,$Country,$Year,$Description,$Images);
$img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/";

print  "<table border='1' cellpadding='0'>";
while ($stmt->fetch()){
print '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Country</th><th>Year</th><th>Description</th><th>Image</th></tr>';
print '<tr>';
print "<td> " .$ID." </td>";
print "<td> " .$Country. " </td>";
print "<td> " .$Year. " </td>";
print "<td> " .$Description." </td>";

print  '<td>'.'<img src="'.$img_url.$row.$Images.'" />'.'</td>';

  ?>

    <td><a href="more.php?ID=<? echo $ID;?>">More Details</td>

    <?

print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';
$stmt->close(); 
?>
```

Tha hardest part was getting it to print into a table. There is also a cell now which offers more details for each line. If you click it, it takes you to a new page. I hope this can be of use to someone.